# What is the equivalent of Java's generic wildcard ("?") in C#?

Tags: java, c#, generics

In JAVA I can create property like

```
public class MyConverter {

private Map<Class<?>, ITypeConverter<?>> converterMap = new HashMap<Class<?>, ITypeConverter<?>>();

...

}
```

how can I do this in C#? What is the equivalent of Java's `?` in C#.
I tried with `T` but `T` is not allowed outide of method or class

Comment: That may not be the best answer.  Googling for "c# equivalent of java wildcard" turns up a few more possibilities.